# gedit top menu invisible when started from terminal and using x11-Forwarding

Tags: ssh, gedit, x11-forwarding

**Given:**
I'm using `export $(dbus-launch)` in my `/etc/bash.bashrc` file as I'm normally running under a non-admin user and need to `su - admin` to do anything dangerous.

**Normal behaviour:**
Go to dash, open gedit.  The top menu is visible.

**Abnormal behaviour**
Go to terminal, type: `gedit`.  Then the top menu is **in**visible. (Problem persists even when sending to bg)

**Additional info:**
I noticed when I do a `gksudo gedit`, that the menu appears below the menu bar of the window instead of the top menu…

**More additional info:**
I just found the culprit: X11-forwarding.  The "abnormal" behaviour stops when I remove `export $(dbus-launch)` from my `bash.bashrc` file.

Does anyone have a clue how to bring *abnormal* back to *normal*? (keeping x11-forwarding?)  I've looked everywhere, but except for a bug on the preferences not showing, I found no solutions to this problem…

Comment: Seems abnormal, here gedit's menu is always accessible whether started from the .desktop (Dash) or the binary (a terminal). You can always use this from a terminal - `gtk-launch gedit` or `gtk-launch gedit /path/to/a/file`. This uses the .desktop to launch

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but alas: using gtk-launch produces the same result.  :(

Comment: @muru: I only noticed now you removed the gnome-terminal tag 4 minutes after I put the question up for a bounty...  Why??? As this only happens when starting from a terminal, I would say it's quite important.  (Asking before adding the tag back in)

Comment: Because it is not apparently specific to gnome-terminal (do you experience different behaviour if you use, say, [tag:xfce4-terminal] instead?). I'd say `x11-forwarding` covers the fact that you're using a terminal. If you feel it doesn't, consider [tag:command-line].

Comment: gtk-launch worked for me on 1604 over X11.  Also surprised that the alias to itself worked. `alias gedit='gtk-launch gedit'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I found the answer after all:

If you're using X11 forwarding, don't forget to look at the `~/.config/` for the user actually running `gedit`!  *Not the `~/.config/` of the user that the application is displayed in!*

In this particular case, deleting the `~/.config/gedit` solved this particular problem as `gedit` just recreates it afterwards. (dumb me: I should have renamed it and looked what the differences were, so I could have posted the perfect answer, but at the time, I was trying to solve another problem)

---

### Original answer:

Too bad no one found any answer, so I'll post my own work-arounds as a "solution"

(I know though they're not really "solutions"; they're just "work-arounds")

1. Use the toolbar for the most-often used commands.
2. Use the Keyboard short-cuts:
   As the only menu-item I'm really missing from the toolbar is "File - Save As", I just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and the menu seems to be coming out of the system menu when using this workaround.  Then just press <kbd>A</kbd> for "As" and you get to the "Save As" dialog...

The same system can be used for <kbd>E</kbd>dit, <kbd>V</kbd>iew, <kbd>S</kbd>earch, <kbd>T</kbd>ools, <kbd>D</kbd>ocuments and <kbd>H</kbd>elp

Comment: +1 because this is close to a problem I'm having... running "sudo gedit" you cannot access any menus even with "<Alt>+E", "<Alt>+F", etc. Something with `/home/user/.config/dconf` vs `/home/root/.config/dconf` or as you say `$~/.config/gedit` vs `#~/.config/gedit`. Additionally people get messages like "** (gedit:12601): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-enabled not supported". Effects 100k+ people?