# Kubuntu/Macbook: Monitor not detected. Mini display port to vga adapter

Tags: kubuntu, display, macbook-pro

I am trying to connect my Macbook Pro to external Samsung VGA monitor via mini display port to VGA adapter. But the monitor is not being detected.

1. It is working fine with OS X
2. It is not detected in Kubuntu only.
3. It works with a coupled mini-display to HDMI and HDMI to VGA.
4. If I unplug the VGA cable from the monitor side, a monitor is detected named DP1. (thats true! the VGA cable with a loose end, with no monitors connected, it gets detected. )

I tried upgrading from Kubuntu 14.04 to 14.10. Still the same.

Product Details:

```
Moelissa Mini Display Port To Vga Adapter  
SUPC: SDL956438123
```

Whether it's plugged in or not, the output of `lsusb` is the  same.

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 05ac:0252 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 05ac:821d Apple, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2513 Standard Microsystems Corp. 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:8509 Apple, Inc. FaceTime HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c05b Logitech, Inc. M-U0004 810-001317 [B110 Optical USB Mouse]
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1a2c:0c21 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8564:1000  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What's the brand name of the adapter?

Comment: Fabby, its Moelissa. bought from snapdeal.
 http://www.snapdeal.com/product/moelissa-mini-display-port-to/2060669589#bcrumbSearch:moelissa%20mini%20display%20vga

Comment: Never use link-only references: **Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://www.snapdeal.com/product/moelissa-mini-display-port-to/2060669589" on this server.

Reference #18.3e25d7c3.1422783168.93831c19**

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide: 1/ The full product name and number&revision 2/ the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: @Fabby, editted.

Comment: Downloading the latest kernel and having a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the [latest kernel Release Candidate](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.x/testing/linux-3.19-rc6.tar.xz) and did a `grep --recursive --ignore-case Moelissa` and the results are: zilch, nada, nothing, rien du tout, nichts, nikske, ничего, नथिंग!

So you basically have 3 options (higher number is more difficult):

1. Do nothing and wait until Linus Torvalds gets to your problem.
2. [Buy one that has Linux support](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=linux%20mini%20displayport%20adapter)
3. Get involved in Linux kernel development and develop a driver yourself

Comment: This is not a USB adapter. this is a mini display port adapter.

Comment: My bad. I was working on too many display problems at once.  Corrected.

Comment: but what about the rest? does the rest of the answer apply to mini display port adapter too?

Comment: Yes!  I just verified my `history` and I did not make a mistake there...  I did search for `Moelissa`. Just when typing the humorous google search, I typed the wrong words in the link!  Your mini-display adapter is not supported by the current nor the latest-and-greatest Linux Kernel... **:-(** Sorry to be the harbinger of bad news...

Comment: i was under an impression that display adapters dont need any drivers or so... correct me if am wrong please. It didnt come with a driver CD for windows either. It works perfect in osX. i didnt install any drivers

Comment: There are no "drivers" under Linux! There is something called "modules" and these perform the same task, so a lot of people *call* them "drivers" because that's what Microsoft calls them.  And every piece of hardware needs a module...  In Linux they're built into the kernel (or not in your case) and on Windows they're mostly pre-installed (look at the size of the `winsxs` directory!) HTH!  ;-)

Comment: Oh, before I forget: the little grey check mark box has to be pushed within the next 6 hours or the bounty will be lost to everyone forever (including you: it does not revert back)

Comment: yeah, fabby, i know. I'm checking this page every hour today :D In case a better answer come? ha ha.. 
Thanks for your support fabby.

Comment: Happened to me too!  http://askubuntu.com/questions/551420/gedit-top-menu-invisible-when-started-from-terminal-and-using-x11-forwarding