# Menu bar missing in gedit

Tags: gedit, menu-bar

I don't know what I did in gedit (and nautilus), but menu bar gone away. Here a screenshot. Actually, menu bar changed but I like the "classic" way, with "File, Edit...". What I did wrong and how I can I fix this?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

Comment: Move the mouse cursor to the top left corner do you see your menu there? I mean does the global menu now is working instead of local menu?

Comment: Take a look at [this forum post](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=14105.0). It says the problem is with ongoing **GTK+3.12**  client side decorations. Seems you either have to wait, or change to another editor, like [medit.](http://mooedit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. It's about GTK+ 3.12. I will start to use medit until this issue get fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gedit top menu invisible when started from terminal and using x11-Forwarding](http://askubuntu.com/questions/551420/gedit-top-menu-invisible-when-started-from-terminal-and-using-x11-forwarding)

Answer (score 6):

if you are using GNOME 3, you can access the preferences via the top menu.

you should have "activities" on the top left corner of your screen. on the right side of activities, you will have gedit. click on it, and you should see the preferences.

Answer (score 5):

Read this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1542489

I decided to use pluma instead of gedit:

```
sudo apt-get install pluma
```

It looks just like gedit did about 2 versions ago. This will work fine (for me) until gedit gets straightened out.

Answer (score 4):

I had a same problem with applications like LibreOffice 5 and terminal and gedit. Menu bar was missing from both of this applications. It occurred after upgrading Ubuntu to 16.04 from 14.04... I used following two commands and it worked for me...

**WARNING: resets all compiz settings.**

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Use above two commands and I hope it will work for you also...

Comment: You should at least explain that the first command **resets all user settings related to Compiz**.

Comment: yes, after resetting compiz, it all worked again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some of `gedit`'s menu items can only be seen when the `indicator-appmenu` is installed. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu
```

Logout and login again. See if the menu of the `gedit` application appears on the top of the **screen** (not on top of the application window). If it does, you should be able to find `Preferences` option there.

If you don't like the menu to appear on the top of the screen (such as I), you may remove it afterward.

```
sudo apt-get remove indicator-appmenu
```

Don't forget to logout and login again.