# No menu bar in gedit 3.18.3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, sudo, gedit

Gedit usually shows the menu bar when the mouse is hovered over the top of Unity (desktop) no matter where or how gedit is displayed. This is ok.

When started from terminal using

```
sudo gedit
```

there is no menu bar anywhere.

[dconf reset -f /org/compiz/](https://askubuntu.com/a/766052/547172) crashed the system.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> does not work.

"To show the menu in the window's title bar go to **Settings >> Appearance >> Behavior** and click **Show Menu** In The Window's Title Bar." from [linuxandubuntu](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus)

This change does work normally but still no menu bar with `sudo gedit`

I could go on with at least 5 other attempts but figure you get the idea.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Good question, but it's like that for all applications run as sudo/root in 16.04 AFAIK. Probably ubuntu developers only "patched" non-root applications and the rest look like gnome3 applications.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation Joakim. I found a reasonably acceptible workaround juggling terminal and 'files' (i don't even know the name of the file browser - that's how new I am...)

Comment: :) It used to be called nautilus (now files), so to open it in terminal simply type sudo nautilus and you will see the same thing. It's really ugly, but not a deal breaker. Once you get used to the terminal, moving files around as root is much quicker. Linux can be a little scary at the beginning, but once you learn more, you will think "how have I ever lived without the terminal" ;) it's that awesome.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - I did not know 'files' and 'nautilsus' were the same. Now several things make sense. I am sure I'll adapt quickly to terminal, have lived partially in window's command prompt since forever and DOS all the way back to the beginning of PC's. (Sometimes I get lazy - drag and drop can be easier on occasion.)

Comment: this is not a duplicate of the stated question. It's a known bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1527590)

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY GTK_MODULES=$GTK_MODULES DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS gedit
```