# Ubuntu 16.04 Ubuntu Software runs but does not install software nor show installed software following dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ and setsid unity

Tags: unity, software-center, compiz, gedit, dconf

I was attempting to resolve a problem with Gedit, found suggestions on [Menu bar missing in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635124/menu-bar-missing-in-gedit)".
I executed the commands: dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ AND setsid unity

Some time following this I attempted to get another text editor using Ubuntu Software and found that it ran OK but did not function properly.
Thanks for any help you can give me.
Jim

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the `dconf` reset had anything to do with Ubuntu Software Center or a malfunction in the other editor. The missing menu bar was a `compiz` problem, meaning the graphic user interface (GUI).

I've found that the new Ubuntu Software that replaced Software Center doesn't work all the time. So, the Synaptic Package Manager might be of help. Go to a terminal by pressing

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

and run this code:

```
sudo apt-get synaptic
```

After the Synaptic package is properly installed, you can run it from the Terminal by executing

```
sudo synaptic
```

After reviewing the help files you'll find yourself in complete control of the packages in your machine.