# No toolbar in gedit

Tags: gnome, gedit

I am under Ubuntu 20.04.02, using Gnome 3.36.8.

My `gedit` (version 3.36.2) does not have a toolbar.
As per [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-gedit-3-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts) (from 2016): 1) that is part of "the new look" of gedit (see also [this](https://blogs.gnome.org/nacho/2014/01/15/gedit-has-a-new-face/)), 2) that has been asked before, 3) there is a workaround via a ppa that "tricks" into downgrading gedit, 4) for those who don't want to "downgrade", a fork of gedit named `pluma` is suggested.

**As of today (2021), is there any way to get the toolbar in gedit?**

I found no dconf setting for that in `org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui`,

**Related** (mostly from about 2016, where the transition occured):

1. [Where are gedit's preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/375049/where-are-gedits-preferences)
2. [Menu bar missing in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/635124/menu-bar-missing-in-gedit)
3. [gedit top menu invisible when started from terminal and using x11-Forwarding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551420/gedit-top-menu-invisible-when-started-from-terminal-and-using-x11-forwarding)
4. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326742
5. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/gedit-has-no-menubar-4175591052/

Answer (score -2):

Excuse me.
Hello, Bro. I have a suggestion for your problem. I'm a newbie, but you can try this option. You can reinstall gedit from terminal to resolve that.
Sorry my English.

Comment: Your English is not bad, but I guess at least some hint to this solving the problem is desirable...